# No more splash screen after switch to tycho

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I recently moved the build of our RCP application from PDE Build to tycho (0.14.0). Everything works fine so far, but the splash screen isn´t shown anymore. The osgi.splashPath property is set correctly and the splash.bmp file is existing in the exported bundle root (the bundle is even active at startup if that matters). Packaging is eclipse-repository. Is there anything else to look for?

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>com.my.client.parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../com.my.client.parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>com.my.client.product</artifactId>
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <product-id>com.my</product-id>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>materialize-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>archive-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>archive-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Edit: ** I integrated the projects on our CI server and the result from there shows the beautiful splash screen - so thanks for your support, problem fixed itself magically...

Comment: can you, please, show us your pom.xml of eclipse-repository?

Comment: sure, edited the question above

Comment: edited and undeleted my answer :)

Comment: Have you checked that the branding plugin is included in the folder "plugins" of the generated product?

Comment: So... what did we learn from this question?

Comment: Local builds behave differntly from CI builds?

Answer (score 1):

the tycho tutorial has a demo build with splash-screen

https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/exercises/Exercise_05_Solution

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the great tutorial which led me through the whole way of migrating the build to tycho. As far as i can see, there is nothing else to do as put a "splash.bmp" file in a bundle and reference the bundle from the product configuration. Anyway the osgi.splashPath property is generated correctly in my config.ini and the splash.bmp file is exisiting in the exported bundle...

Comment: my point was did you try to build the tutorial example? it should have a working splash screen. Then see what could be the difference between the tutorial which works and your example which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, your pom is ok. can you check your build.properties to see if the `splash.bmp` is marked to be exported? I know you said that the plug-in contains your splash, but just to confirm...
I don't know if this will help, but here's mine `pom.xml` that works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.germantech.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../br.com.germantech.parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.germantech</groupId>
    <artifactId>br.com.germantech</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.13</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
                    <createArtifactRepository>true</createArtifactRepository>
                    <compress>true</compress>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-repository</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <profile>Installer</profile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <products>
                        <product>
                            <id>br.com.germantech.ecfNfe</id>
                            <rootFolder>germantechEcfNfe</rootFolder>
                            <attachId>${project.version}</attachId>
                        </product>
                    </products>

                    <formats>
                        <win32>zip</win32> 
                        <linux>tar.gz</linux>
                        <macosx>tar.gz</macosx>
                    </formats>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using tycho 0.14.0

Comment: Thanks for your pom.xml - I added the configuration part to explicitly point tycho to the product id, which also had no effect on the splash screen ;-) The build.properties file contains the splash.bmp entry in bin.includes.